# Executable generated from Pyinstaller not closing properly

Tags: pyinstaller, executable

I generated an exe using Pyinstaller and I notice that even though I close it, it keeps running in the background and I have to end task from the task manager for it to properly close. Any ideas on why?

I expected that when closing the window of the app, it will also and the task.